# How *do* NGOs, think tanks, and governments weigh income/consumption tradeoffs/transfers at different income levels?

Tags: public-economics, welfare-economics, soft-question, development-economics, social-choice

In considering policies and transfers, how do we (economists, NGOs, governments & think tanks) *weigh income (consumption) tradeoffs between the poor & the very poor?*

E.g., 'is giving 100 USD/year to someone earning 300 USD/year valued more than 1000 USD/year for someone earning 2000 USD/year'?

- How do they think about/model this (and justify this)
- How do they measure the underlying values and come up with a function or set of weights?
- Are these weights publicly reported?

Comment: This Q is quite broad please consider narrowing it down or splitting it into separate questions

Comment: OK, I will split it into 2-3 questions, thanks!